# Cast error on GridView Sorting event

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I'm intercepting the RowDatabound event and using:

```
DbDataRecord record = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Row.DataItem;
```

to get access to the unbound data source columns. It works fine on page load and when I apply a filter to the dataset. However, when I attempt to initate a sort on a GridView Column, I get :

```
Error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord'
```

I think I've traced the root issue back to the bind method used in the sort:

```
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();        
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();        
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (eventArgs != null)
    {
        DataSet SortedData = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.Sort = eventArgs.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(eventArgs.SortExpression);
        SortedData.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[0].DefaultView.ToTable());
        GridView1.DataSource = SortedData;
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.DataSource =  ds;
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I remember this was a major pain to figure out because only Dataset had a Sort Property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to sort the Dataset, I appended the sort direction and column from the viewstate to the query before binding it to the grid using SqlDataReader. Looks like I went out of my way to make a simple thing hard to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

Since you assign a `DataSet` to `GridView1.DataSource`, then the type of `e.Row.DataItem` in the `RowDatabound` event will be a `DataRowView` instead of a `System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord`. You need to change this:

```
DbDataRecord record = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Row.DataItem;
```

to this:

```
DataRowView record = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Comment: Can you add the code where you bind the GridView? I guess you need to do the sorting in the database query instead of using DataSet Sort property

Comment: Couldn't I re-cast the Dataset ds to a data structure compatible with DbDataRecord?

Comment: Yes you could, the point is if you bind `List<DbDataRecord>` at first load, then you must also bind `List<DbDataRecord>` when sorting.